# Chain modifications in events

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate

ASP.NET Boilerplate [have EventBus system](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EventBus-Domain-Events) and we have events

- EntityCreatingEventData
- EntityCreatedEventData
- EntityDeletingEventData
- EntityDeletedEventData
- **…**

But these events work after calling `SaveChanges()` (data already in DB). We want event system before calling `SaveChanges()`, when data is not written in DB yet

We also want recursive event system, for example :

creating object A => call EntityCreatingBeforeSaveEventData(a) => in this handle we create new object B and call Repository.Insert(b) => call EntityCreatingBeforeSaveEventData(b)... 
And this process calling while exist any modification in DB Context.

Comment: Please apply some proper formatting to your question before you want us to look at it in detail.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What are you asking?

Comment: My question: we should to have event system that was write top , and I asking how we can do it or maybe somebody realized a similar system.

Answer (score 1):

## Dependent on `entity.Id`

It is not possible to have a domain event system before calling `SaveChanges()`.

- ASP.NET Boilerplate detects changes *when* calling `SaveChanges()`.
- Recursive events can cause an infinite loop — see [#1616](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/1616).
- An object with an `Id` that has not been set (auto-generated) cannot be identified.

If you are dependent on such a system, then it may be poor separation of concerns.

## Independent of `entity.Id`

You can use `IEventBus` directly.

Trigger event:

```cs
public class AManager : DomainService, IAManager
{
    public void CreateA()
    {
        var a = new A();
        Repository.Insert(a);
        EventBus.Trigger(new EntityCreatingBeforeSaveEventData<A>
        {
             Property = a.SomeProperty // Can pass other properties
        });
    }
}

public class BManager : DomainService, IBManager
{
    // Similar to above
}
```

Handle event:

```cs
public class AHandler : IEventHandler<EntityCreatingBeforeSaveEventData<A>>, ITransientDependency
{
    public IBManager BManager { get; set; }

    public void HandleEvent(EntityCreatingBeforeSaveEventData<A> eventData)
    {
        var aSomeProperty = eventData.Property;
        BManager.CreateB();
    }
}
```

Comment: "ASP.NET Boilerplate detects changes when calling SaveChanges()." - yes, but we can modify source code ABP with insert call events into SaveChanges() before write into BD. "Recursive events can cause an infinite loop — see #1616." - we understand this problem and we ready to live with this. "An object with an Id that has not been set (auto-generated) cannot be identified." - we generate ID in code. Maybe you know what we can do with it?

Comment: Since the modifications are so specific to your project, you should fork the framework.